# click button on a dialog opened by p/invoke

Tags: c#, pinvoke, ui-automation

This code opens a Dialog by clicking a Button on a Form

```
IntPtr m = FindWindow("TForm1", "Smart Design");

IntPtr b = FindWindowEx(m, IntPtr.Zero, "TButton", "Update List");
SendMessage(b, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

How to click OK button on the opened dialog?

I tried this code but it fails:

```
IntPtr d = FindWindow("TDialog4", "Information");

IntPtr k = FindWindowEx(d, IntPtr.Zero, "TButton7", "OK");
SendMessage(k, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
```

Comment: If you want to automate UI, use UIAutomation

Answer (score -1):

I'd try sending the dialog a WM_COMMAND instead.

```
    private const uint WM_COMMAND = 0x0111;
    private const int BM_CLICKED = 245;

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, 
    int wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parentHandle,
    IntPtr childAfter, string className,  string  windowTitle);

    SendMessage(k, WM_COMMAND, (BM_CLICKED << 16) | 1, k);
```

Comment: how to get the dialog handle? it is a child of the main form.